# issue playing video in iOS sdk MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, movieplayer

I am trying to play video in iPhone, following is the code i have used.

It keep loading but video doesn't play, am i missing anything.

Player is launched but it sonly shows loading and never play the video.

I have also imported  **MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h**

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"test_output" ofType:@"mov"];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
             moviePath];

_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
     }


        - (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
           MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
          removeObserver:self
          name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
          object:player];

if ([player
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
 }
```

[image: As shown in screenshot it keeps loading only]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check whether your movie file is added to your project or not.

Second, try creating path with `fileURLWithPath`. Replace your following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:moviePath];
```

with

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
```

Comment: Thanks Dear, fileurlwithpath worked.. You saved my day... Thanks :)

Comment: @Satish if my answer helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as correct one :).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any code which calls play method of _moviePlayer.moviePlayer.

Try adding following statement to your code.

[_moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];

Add this statement before [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Buddy your code seems to be correct. The problem is definitely with the URL. Double check whether url is correct or not.